# A sum of products symmetric in the images under all the embeddings

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}\subset K\subset \mathbb{C}$ where $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$ be all the embeddings $K\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Is it true that elements of $\mathbb{C}$ like $\sigma_1(x)\sigma_2(y)+\sigma_2(x)\sigma_3(y)+\dots+\sigma_n(x)\sigma_1(y)\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: To be clear your sum is $\sigma_n(x)\sigma_1(y)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sigma_i(x)\sigma_{i+1}(y)$?

Comment: Yes. This is the sum I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general when $n\ge 3$ (trivially true otherwise).

First one shoud notice that your sum depends on the numbering of the set of embeddings $\Gamma$.

Suppose for simplicity that $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb Q$ (otherwise your statement has little chance to be true). And suppose 
the statement is true. For any $\tau\in\Gamma$, there exists a permutation $\phi_\tau$ of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ such that for all $i\le n$, we have $\tau\sigma_i=\sigma_{\phi_\tau(i)}$. Now apply $\tau$ to $\sum_i \sigma_i(x)\sigma_{i+1}(y)$ (identify $n+1$ to $1$), we get
$$ \sum_i \sigma_{\phi_\tau(i)}(x)\sigma_{\phi_\tau(i+1)}(y)
=\sum_i \sigma_i(x)\sigma_{i+1}(y). $$
So 
$$\sum_i (\sigma_{i+1}(y)-\sigma_{\phi_\tau(\phi_\tau^{-1}(i)+1)}(y))\sigma_i(x)=0$$ 
Fix $y$ and let $x$ varies in $K$. Using Dedekind's independance lemma and then make $y$ vary in $K$, we have
$$\phi_{\tau}^{-1}(i+1)=\phi_\tau^{-1}(i)+1$$ 
for all $i$. Now take $\tau=\sigma_2\sigma_1^{-1}$. This implies that $\phi_\tau(1)=2$. The above relation then imply that $\phi_\tau(i)=i+1$. In other words, $\tau\sigma_i=\sigma_{i+1}$ and $\tau^i\sigma_1=\sigma_i$. Thus $\tau$ has order $n$ and $\Gamma$ is cyclic.

Conclusion: if $\sum_i \sigma_i(x)\sigma_{i+1}(y)\in \mathbb Q$ for all $x,y\in K$, then $\Gamma$ is cyclic and the numbering $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$ of elements of $\Gamma$ follows the rule that $\sigma_{i+1}=\tau\sigma_i$ for some generator $\tau$ of $\Gamma$. The converse is easily see to be true.

Comment: I think your manipulations of varying $x$ and $y$ could be replaced by taking a [normal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis) for $K/Q$, and by taking $x$ and $y$ to be two among them. This could simplify things, I suppose. P.S. The link is to supply a reference, not to intervene with your own notations. Thanks.

Comment: @awllower: I don't know. But why not, you could try. I would be happy to see a different solution.

Comment: I write a messy answer. Hope you like it. :D

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make a counter-example. I don't really understand the more advanced answers.

---

If we take $$K  = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$$ be the splitting field of $X^3-2$, and set $y=1$ then we have six automorphisms which are defined by how they map the pair $(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$ to

$$\begin{array}{|r|l|c|} \hline
(\sqrt[3]{2},+\sqrt{-3}) & (\omega\sqrt[3]{2},+\sqrt{-3}) & (\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2},+\sqrt{-3}) \\ \hline
(\sqrt[3]{2},-\sqrt{-3}) & (\omega\sqrt[3]{2},-\sqrt{-3}) & (\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2},-\sqrt{-3}) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

If we choose these automorphisms in this order

```
1,2,3
6,5,4
```

then given $x=y=\sqrt[3]{2}$ the form is $$(1 \cdot \omega + \omega \cdot \omega^2 + \omega^2 \cdot \omega^2 + \omega^2 \cdot \omega + \omega \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1)(\sqrt[3]{2})^2 = \sqrt{-3} \not \in \mathbb Q$$

---

on the other hand I think the form is invariant if you pick the order

```
1,5,3
4,2,6
```

Comment: The two definitions of $K$ don't coincide. You meant the second one ?

Comment: @QiL'8, thanks you I am a beginner so I got it wrong: I guess I meant the splitting field of X^3-2.

Comment: anyway the key here was given by you: the order in which we choose automorphisms let's us choose them in a very odd "non-symmetric" order to get irrational values.

Comment: OK, I edit to make clear it is the splitting field.

Comment: @QiL'8, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

First let us modify the proof given by Qil'8:
If $x$ and $y$ are two different numbers among a normal basis of $K/Q$, then $\sigma_i(x)$ are linearly independent. Hence, by use of the same method as Qil'8, we can prove the same result, instead of letting $x$ and $y$ vary and using Dedekind theorem.
Another aproach would be to take a normal basis generated by $\theta$, and write
$x=\sum_ia_i\sigma_i(\theta)$
$y=\sum_ib_i\sigma_i(\theta)$,
so that the expression becomes
$\alpha=\sum_m\sum_n\sum_ia_mb_n\sigma_i\sigma_m(\theta)\sigma_i\sigma_n(\theta)$.
Write moreover $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_{\phi_i(j)}$. Then We shall compute the stabilizer $G_{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$. By direct computations we find that $\sigma_j$ belongs to $G_{\alpha}$ if and only if
$\sum_ia_{\phi_i^{-1}\phi_j^{-1}(m)}b_{\phi_{i+1}^{-1}\phi_j^{-1}(n)}=\sum_ia_{\phi_i^{-1}(m)}b_{\phi_{i+1}^{-1}(n)}$ for every $m$ and $n$, leading us to the following equation:
$\sum_ia_{\phi_i^{-1}(m)}(b_{\phi_{i+1}^{-1}(n)}-b_{\phi_{\phi_j^{-1}(i)+1}^{-1}\phi_j^{-1}(n)})=0$
For any given $j$, we can adjust the coefficients so that the second factor is $0$, except at one place. And we can set the coefficient for $a$ to be $1$ at that place, thus contradicting the condition. Hence it is generally not rational.
P.S. The purpose is not to provide a shorter answer, but to view the general case, and, indeed, for some fixed $x$ and $y$, we can explicitly compute the above expressions and thus determine the size of the stabiliser.
**P.P.S.**
We can compute the above expressions in the general case, i.e. with $a$ and $b$ varying, thus determine which extensions could satisfy the requirements:
It is seen that, if such an expressions are fixed for all $a$ and $b$, then we would obtain:
$b_{\phi_{i+1}^{-1}(n)}-b_{\phi_{\phi_j^{-1}(i)+1}^{-1}\phi_j^{-1}(n)}=0$,
for any $i$, $j$, and $n$. Thus we conclude that $\phi_{i+1}^{-1}(n)=\phi_{\phi_j^{-1}(i)+1}^{-1}\phi_j^{-1}(n)$, that is,
$\phi_j\phi_{\phi_j^{-1}(i)+1}=\phi_{i+1}$.
Rendering this into the language of automorphisms, we find that
$\sigma_j\sigma_{\phi_j^{-1}(i)+1}=\sigma_{i+1}$,
so that $\phi_j^{-1}(i)+1=\phi_j^{-1}(i+1)$.
And this condition has been shown to imply that the extension is cyclic, and the automorphisms are ordered in ascending order according to its exponent with respect to a specific generator. Hence this expression indeed shows that in general the expression is not a rational number. And, let me emphasize again, from this above equation, one can compute the stabilisers of given $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You say the $\sigma_i(x)$ are linearly independent, but only over $\mathbb Q$, right ? Then what is the next step ?

Comment: Yes, that is over $Q$. And then substitute into your relations the normal basis expression to simplify things. Or one can employ the following calculations and assume that $x$ and $y$ come from some normal basis, for example, assume $x=\theta$ and $y=\sigma(\theta)$.

Comment: But how do you order the $\sigma$'s ? Note that the original statement is true for cyclic extensions when the automorphisms are ordered in a suitable way.

Comment: @QiL'8 I edited: hope it helps.